# Solve equations involving “obvious” set operations

Tags: set, isabelle

I regularly find that “auto” will not solve an equation that seems simple enough to me, at least using some search on terms involving `∪`, `∩` and `-`.

```
Failed to finish proof⌂:
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ArityAnalysis.Afix Aexp Γ⋅(Aexp e⋅n) f|` (fv Γ ∪ fv e - domA Γ) =
    ArityAnalysis.Afix Aexp Γ⋅(Aexp e⋅n) f|` ((fv Γ ∪ fv e - domA Γ) ∩ - domA Γ)
```

I can work around it (e.g. `by auto (metis Diff_eq Diff_idemp)`), but I wonder if there exists some automation that I’m missing. Maybe some dedicated simp set like `ac_simps` for set operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasoning about sets in Isabelle2013-2 is mainly done by the classical reasoner using introduction and elimination rules that attempt a point-wise solution. I do not know of any setup for reasoning about boolean algebras by rewriting in Isabelle. (Remark: The Regular-Expressions entry in the Archive of Formal Proofs provides a method `regexp` to deal with such equalities, but it is not integrated with other automated methods like `auto`.) Fortunately, all the theorems you need are there in the HOL library, but they are not in the simpset by default, because they would sometimes work against you. In your example, it suffices to add `Diff_eq` to the simpset.

With more complicated set expressions, it may be hard to find a set of normalising rewrite rules. Therefore, I prefer to let the classical reasoner with its setup work on the set equality. This requires that the equality occurs as a subgoal, i.e., it must not be hidden under function applications. That is, you want to prove `f x = f y` by proving `x = y`, which the rule `arg_cong` expresses. Adding `arg_cong` as `[intro]` to `auto` directs it in that direction, but it may not always work because HO unification can get in the way. In that case, it usually suffices to specify the `f` explicitly as in

```
by(auto intro: arg_cong[where f="%x. ArityAnalysis.Afix Aexp Γ⋅(Aexp e⋅n) f|` x"])
```

Comment: Heh, that reminds me a lot of equational reasoning in Agda. And it would be great if there was a way to use `arg_cong` as `intro!` without it matching with `f = (λ x.x)`.